# Set cache expire headers for static files without access to nginx configuration (Django + Gunicorn)

Tags: python, django, caching, nginx, gunicorn

I have my Django app up and running using Gunicorn+Nginx on a shared hosting, but I don't have access to my nginx configuration file (because of shared hosting, I create an "app" on my hosting Control panel which is automatically added as a virtual host with a specific port, and I use that port to start my Gunicorn).

Is there a way to set my cache expire headers for static files like css and jpg? Nginx obviously doesn't have something like .htaccess which would make this easier.

Maybe there's a way that would make Django or Gunicorn "push" some configuration (location etc.) to Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the HTTP headers that are returned in your app's responses without access to the web server sitting in front of Django. [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers) provides a number of scenarios with instructions on what to do. Hopefully this is enough to get you started.

I'd actually recommend this over changing it in your web server configuration as it means your caching configuration is part of your application code, and your application's behaviour isn't determined by an 'outside' configuration.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for getting back to me, the thing is that I need to set the headers for my static (css, js, jpg basically) files. Sorry I didn't include it in the question itself! 

I'm using per view caching already. :)

Comment: @Elliot how are you currently serving static files? Are you bypassing Django / WSGI and serving them straight from the web server? If so, you could serve them through Django using a package like Whitenoise (https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise) - which'll let you control the response headers.

Comment: Yea, they're served as a "custom app" which is a symlink to static folder in my project folder.